# C# How to compare multiple array values (strings) in if-statement?

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I am making a tic-tac-toe game using an array. And to see if someone wins I have to check if there is a winning combination.
Here's my array with the board

```
string[] board = new string[9] { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " , " ", " ", " " };
```

At first, the board is empty. Then the 2 players start to place 'X's and 'O's.
But I can't compare, for example, if the first line is full of 'X's.
The code below doesn't work for some reason. And I don't know why?

```
board[0].Equals(board[1]).Equals(board[2]).Equals("X")
```

I also tried with `board[0]==board[1]==board[2]=="X"`

Here is the complete if-statement (these are the winning combinations):

```
if (table[0].Equals(table[1]).Equals(table[2]).Equals("X") || table[3].Equals(table[4]).Equals(table[5]).Equals("X") || table[6].Equals(table[7]).Equals(table[8]).Equals("X") ||
            table[0].Equals(table[3]).Equals(table[6]).Equals("X") || table[1].Equals(table[4]).Equals(table[7]).Equals("X") || table[2].Equals(table[5]).Equals(table[8]).Equals("X") ||
            table[0].Equals(table[4]).Equals(table[8]).Equals("X") || table[7].Equals(table[4]).Equals(table[3]).Equals("X"))
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You cant stack statements like that. `board[0].Equals(board[1])` return a boolean so lets say it returns true. then you are doing `true.Equals(board[2])` which makes no sense

Comment: Totally makes sense :/ Any suggestions? Because using `==` works fine in python, but not in C#.

Comment: `board[0].Equals(board[1])` returns Boolean value and then you are trying to do Equals with `board[1]` which string and that comparison will return always false. About comparing using `==` did you debug the code and check if board has proper values in 0,1 and 2 places?

Comment: Try chaning if condition to `if(board[0] == "X" && board[1] == "X" && board[2] == "X")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c#, you can't use

```
if (a == b == c)
```

Instead you have to be explicit:

```
if (a == b && b == c)
```

So instead of

```
board[0].Equals(board[1]).Equals(board[2]).Equals("X")
```

You have to write

```
board[0] == "X" && board[1] == "X" && board[2] == "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `board[0].Equals(board[1]).Equals(board[2]).Equals("X")` to `String.Equals(board[0], board[1]) && String.Equals(board[1], board[2]) && String.Equals(board[2], "X")`.

Here's [documentation on comparing strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-compare-strings) in c#.